# Implement SMPP in Python

Tags: python, sms, smpp

Have you ever heard of really working python-libraries for the realization of the SMPP client and the SMPP server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't try any of these but it seems there are a couple of SMPP libraries for Python.  Of course, most of the projects are dead.  Two may be worth looking into though:

**Pythomnik3k**
The name suggests that this is Python 3 only, but there has been a Python 2 version, too.  You may need to ask the author to send you `pythomnic-6.0.tar.gz` (I downloaded that sometime last year).
http://www.pythomnic3k.org/download.html

**python-smpp**
This one seems to be a brand new project.  Implementation from scratch.  Looks clean on the first sight.  Currently it is very client-focused.
https://github.com/dmaclay/python-smpp

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a library that is reasonably complete and well tested for PDU parsing.

https://github.com/mozes/smpp.pdu

It can be used with any protocol implementation, including this one in Twisted.

https://github.com/mozes/smpp.twisted

Answer (score 1):

Pythomnic3k application framework indeed contains a complete SMPP 3.4 library in Python *3*.

Here: http://www.pythomnic3k.org/download.html (see SMPP protocol pack).

If you are using the framework, then sending SMS is as easy as

```
xa = pmnc.transaction.create()
xa.smpp.submit("1234567890", "hello")
xa.execute()
```

but if you need just the library, with PDU parsing and stuff, you can find it in lib/smpp34.

Comment: Dmitry, can you tell how complete is it? Can used on both client & server side?

Comment: The library a complete SMPP 3.4 implementation,

Comment: The library contains a complete SMPP 3.4 implementation, with PDUs and errors and everything, but transport agnostic. The Pythomnic3k framework adds TCP transport and can be used as ESME (endpoint) of any type. Therefore an application can be written to send SMS and receive as well.